# ext-zip trouble

Tags: craft3, php, updates, mamp

## Issue:

```
craftcms/cms 3.3.9 requires ext-zip * -> the requested PHP extension zip is missing from your system.
```

## Details:

I am running on `MAMP Pro 5.3`. Currently using `PHP 7.3.3` (but previous versions had the same issue). `Mac OS Catalina`.
I do not seem to be able to get ext-zip on my machine, and thusly not use many of the updated craft installs.

## Attempted Solutions:

Install for macOS

https://stackoverflow.com/a/58300437

Install in MAMP

https://stackoverflow.com/a/59293432

```
cd /{php ext path}
pecl install zip
php --re zip | grep zip // version 1.15.4
```

(terminal php is set to mamp version)

```
# php7.3.3.ini (I also tried extension=zip.so)
; If you wish to have an extension loaded automatically, use the following
; syntax:
;
;   extension=modulename
    extension="/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.3.3/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20180731/zip.so"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was due to a path problem.
Path was set to

```
/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.3.3/lib/php
```

but should have been

```
/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.3.3/bin
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I'm getting `pecl` command not found. I've tried working through https://stackoverflow.com/a/54883630/639538 but with no joy.

Comment: Managed to get somewhere with `pecl` with https://tobschall.de/2019/10/03/pear-on-catalina/. But now when I cd into my PHP bin and run `pecl install zip` I get "No releases available for package 'pecl.php.net/zip' install failed".

Comment: [Chad's comment](https://github.com/craftcms/cms/issues/4927#issuecomment-576940030) under craftcms issue #4927 is helpful -- at least in terms of “the Craft system report is looking at MAMP's php info, whereas composer is looking at the system php info, which didn't have zip installed”. But I'm still no closer.

Comment: Promising insights from Brian about [how to run Composer more context sensitively](https://github.com/craftcms/cms/issues/4927#issuecomment-593977141). Will investigate further when I have time.

Answer (score 4):

None of various attempts to get ext-zip going under Catalina had worked for me, including the above, but here’s what did, with thanks to [Chad](https://github.com/craftcms/cms/issues/4927#issuecomment-576940030) for showing the essence of the issue:

> “the Craft system report is looking at MAMP's php info, whereas composer is looking at the system php info, which didn't have zip installed.”

…and then [Brian](https://github.com/craftcms/cms/issues/4927#issuecomment-593977141) for what worked for me:

> “run composer on the command line specifically against the MAMP version of PHP”

Like this:

`/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/<phpX.X>/bin/php </path/to/composer> create-project craftcms/craft </path/to/project-folder>`

In my case:

- `<phpX.X>` is `php7.3.3`
- `</path/to/composer>` is `/usr/local/bin/composer`